# JMeter | Groovy | Replace a substring randomly from some places of a large captured value

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am doing scripting in *JMeter* and facing issues in mid.

*Requirement* is to replace **"cond":false** with **"cond":true** randomly for some of the line items from captured value and pass it to next request.

```
Captured value:-
```

operationBPlans={"benefit_actual":"undefined","cond":false,"value":"45672ca3784fdb0,"benefit_state":"Awaiting Approval"}{"benefit_actual":"123","cond":false,"value":"2ca3784fdb0e8510c4ea47,"benefit_state":"Awaiting Approval"}{"benefit_actual":"184","cond":false,"value":"3784fd2cab0e8510c4ea47,"benefit_state":"Awaiting Approval"}{"benefit_actual":"539","cond":false,"value":"8510c43784fd2cab0eea47,"benefit_state":"Awaiting Approval"}..........

*Note:-* snapshot of captured data is below

[image]

Can I get a helping hand for this

Thanks

Comment: post your snapshot as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following snippet of [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy):

```
def operationBPlans = vars.get('operationBPlans')
def matcher = operationBPlans =~ /"cond":false/

while (matcher.find()) {
    operationBPlans = operationBPlans.replaceFirst(matcher.group(0), '"cond":' + org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextBoolean())
}

vars.put('operationBPlans', operationBPlans)
```

Comment: **Getting Error->**

2022-07-19 22:32:09,324 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: original for class: Script12
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
 at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:93) ~[java.scripting:?]

Comment: probably a copy-paste issue, change all occurrences of `original` to `operationBPlans`

Comment: It is working.
Just one more question Can you give a small explanation of how the code **randomly** changes some values {Which particular piece of code is responsible for that}